# iOS Detect URLs in PDF displayed in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview

I'm currently displaying a pdf document in an UIWebView.

```
[...]
[viewerWebView setDataDetectorTypes: UIDataDetectorTypeLink];
[viewerWebView performSelectorInBackground:@selector(loadRequest:) withObject:requestObj];
[viewerWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[...]
(The code is shortened and is only here to show the main part of how I display the pdf in an UIWebView)
```

I am desperately looking for a solution to make a url inside this pdf "tappable" (It's a hyperlink to a website). I know that there is something like "CGPDF" but I'm not quite sure how to implement that to be used with a UIWebView. I'd be glad to be able to further use that WebView and not another way to display a pdf. If anyone's been struggling with this before and is aware of a solution or knows a good tutorial online, I'd highly appreciate a answer.

Thanks in advance, 
Patrick.

Comment: I'm totally aware that this is not written in Swift btw. I'm going to rewrite my apps soon ;-) If you got a solution in Swift - no problem!

Answer (score 1):

With `UIWebView`, your options will be limited to either

1) Implement code that extracts text from a PDF, scans it for links, processes it and then use [`UIGraphicsSetPDFContextDestinationForRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html) to add links to your files. You'll have to re-render the content which is both a slow and lossy process, but for simple PDF documents this might be slow but works well enough.

2) Re-implementing everything, starting with `CGContextDrawPDFPage` You still need special code to extract text (very much non-trivial, be prepared to dig into what CMaps are and how text has to be converted to get unicode)

We did (2) in the commercial available [PSPDFKit SDK](https://pspdfkit.com/) that currently works on iOS and Android. On iOS you can set [autodetectLinkTypes](https://pspdfkit.com/guides/ios/current/annotations/link-annotations/) to `PSPDFTextCheckingTypeAll` to enable such detection.